# Value of the input is not preserved when it is an HTML array

Tags: forms

Suppose, we have a form, containing 3 elements:

1. Checkbox with special name 'name[attached]', indicating that it is a part of an array of checkboxes.
2. Text input
3. Submit button

### Code

```
function bundles_test_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form['name[attached]'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#required' => false,
        '#attributes' => array('name' => 'name[attached]'),
        );

    $form['date'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#required' => false,
        );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        );

    return $form;
}

function bundles_test_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
{
    if (isset($form_state['input']['name']['attached']))
    {
        if ($form_state['input']['date'] === '')
        {
            form_set_error("date", 'date is required');
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

When the form throws an error, the checkbox must be checked, but it is not. When I change the name to "name" or anything that it not the array, it works correctly. So the error is caused by the non-standard name of the input.

Comment: why you are using name[attached] instead of name_attached?

Comment: @drupality Because in the real code there is an array of courses and a checkbox must be created to attach them. I don't know how many courses there are and is using an array of inputs.

Comment: Does `$form['name[attached]']` actually produce the markup you'd expect? I would have thought you'd have to explicitly set a `'#name' => 'name[attached]'` on the element itself

Comment: @Clive I explicitly set `'#attributes' => array('name' => 'name[attached]')`

Comment: @Clive Seems, that Drupal core doesn't support such array inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this should work

```
    function mm_definition_of_the_form($form, &$form_state) {
      //other code
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

      if (isset($form_state['check_field'])) {
        //set default value of the field
      }
    }

    function mm_definition_of_the_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
      //if is error
      $form_state['check_field'] = TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: So, no way to fix it without manually setting the value?

Comment: @user4035 AFAIC no.